# How to solve this error signaled in parallel query server ORA-12801 when delete

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When i run this delete statement

```
delete /*+ PARALLEL(19) */  
  from billing_lines
 where id_service in (select before_line from number_change)
   and id_service not in (select max(a.new_line)
                             from number_change a, number_change bef
                            where a.new_line = bef.before_line
                              and not exists(select null from billing_lines f where f.id_contract= a.id_contract)
                            group by a.id_contract);
```

I get this error

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P003
ORA-12853: insufficient memory for PX buffers: current 12192K, max needed 6255360K
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 65560 bytes of shared memory ("
ORA-06512: at line 28
```

What is the problem. Do I have to increase the memory?

Any suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Oracle version

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for HPUX: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1):

We need memory for each parallel thread in order to pass data between the threads and back to the coordinator.  The more threads you have, the more memory you need.

"parallel 19" could give you up to 38 processes (19 producers, 19 consumers). Try reducing that, otherwise you probably need to bump up your SGA